# customizing installation directory in install4j

Tags: java, directory, install4j

I am building a setup in install4j which will be run for each client of a marketing agency.  There is one installer, but the user can run it more than once, specifying a different clientId value at the installation time.  In the end, I would like to end up with a directory structure like this:

on Mac:

```
/Applications/MYPRODUCTNAME-clientID1/
/Applications/MYPRODUCTNAME-clientID2/
/Applications/MYPRODUCTNAME-clientID3/
```

on Windows:

```
/Program Files/MYPRODUCTNAME-clientID1/
/Program Files/MYPRODUCTNAME-clientID2/
/Program Files/MYPRODUCTNAME-clientID3/
```

Where the IDs are entered at installation time, in independent installer runs.  The IDs are not known in advance - I can't build as many installers as there are IDs.
Ideally, on Mac, I would also prefer to change the name of the launcher file, so that it can be easily discerned from the others in Spotlight search.
I've been playing with Directory Resolver - no luck, especially on Mac which seams to produce a broken launcher on every attempt to change its directory structure.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can change the installation directory by calling

```
context.setInstallationDirectory(...);
```

in a "Run script" action or any code snippet in install4j.

Changing launcher names at runtime is not directly supported by install4j.

Comment: it makes you return a true/false i take it return true then?

Comment: Yes, that means that the action succeeded

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this:

At activation of the Location window:

```
systemInstallPath = context.getVariable( "sys.programFilesDir" ); // if Windows
if( systemInstallPath == null || systemInstallPath.isEmpty() ) // assume Mac
  systemInstallPath = "/Applications";
context.setInstallationDirectory( new File( systemInstallPath ) );
```

Then at activation of Installation window:

```
final Boolean confirmedUpdate = context.getBooleanVariable("sys.confirmedUpdateInstallation");
if( confirmedUpdate == null || !confirmedUpdate ) {
  final File originalInstallDir = context.getInstallationDirectory();
  final String clientId = ( String )context.getVariable( "clientId" );
  final File clientInstallDir = new File( originalInstallDir, "MYPRODUCTNAME-" + clientId );
  context.setInstallationDirectory( clientInstallDir );
}
```

That did the trick.