# Install4j - how to specify the folder on the root drive?

Tags: java, install4j

In install4j, is there a variable for "root directory" of `%PROGRAMFILES%` ?

For example if `D:\Program Files` was where program files is, i want to make my app's default installation location at `D:\MyApp`

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such built-in installer variable, but you can define it yourself by adding a "Set a variable" action and setting its "Script" property to

```
WinFileSystem.getProgramFilesDirectory().toPath().getRoot().toString()
```

Comment: OK I have this variable set. What do I do with it?

Comment: I had to go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066525/customizing-installation-directory-in-install4j